# craft/app: gitignore, or no?

Tags: best-practice, updates

Just looking for pros and cons here, I guess. My gut says to let updates flow through version control, but the part of me that wants to give up web design and become a mountain man says it might be beneficial if the client was at least able to patch in critical updates if necessary.

Thought I remember glancing at a conversation about this in the Slack channel, but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 2):

**No.** Keep `craft/app` in your repo.

> **Disclaimer:** This is my own personal opinion. The topic comes up with some frequency on Craft Slack, and you will find advocates of both approaches. I fully expect to see an opposing position posted by someone else.

**Benefits to keeping `app` in your repo...**

1. You can properly vet an update, and make sure it does not create any problems in your site before pushing that update to production.
2. You have a guarantee that every environment (dev, staging, production) all contain the exact same version of Craft. This means that you can take advantage of specific features with confidence, and similarly, rule out bugs which may have been fixed between Craft versions.
3. You can prevent your client from "accidentally" upgrading, and potentially making a mess. Though it is rare, some breaking changes (or new bugs) are occasionally introduced when updating.